# Why is my array saving and printing not the chars?

Tags: arrays, c, char

I want to print random chars and save them all in one array.
But the problem is, the array saves something - but not the chars printed/generated before.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

char get_symbol(int m);

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));    
    char array[1][5];
    char y;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        y = get_symbol(rand()%3);
        printf("%c", sym);
        y = array[i];
    }
    
    printf("\n\n");
    
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("%s", array[i]);
    }
}

char get_symbol(int m){
    
    char s;
    switch(m){
        case 0: s = 'A'; break;
        case 1: s = 'B'; break;
        case 2: s = 'C'; break;
        default: break;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] show the expected output vs actual output.

Comment: Also please a [mcve]. What is `sym`?

Comment: `y = array[i];` - did you mean `array[i] = y;`?

Comment: Did you read the compiler warnings? You should consider them as errors.

Comment: @UnholySheep even `array[i] = y;` is wrong. `y` is a `char` but `array[i]` is not.

Comment: @mallChad23 The variable sym used in this statement printf("%c", sym) is undeclared.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this, explanations are in the comments:

```
int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  char array[5];              // you just want an array of 5 chars
  char y;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    y = get_symbol(rand() % 3);
    printf("%c", y);          // sym is unknown, you probably wanted to print y
    array[i] = y;             // you have reversed the assignment
  }

  printf("\n\n");

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%c", array[i]);   // use %c here, you want to print 5 single chars
  }                           // not 5 strings

  fflush(stdout);             // flush output buffer. maybe not necessary
}
```

**Bonus:**

Your `get_symbol` function is overly complicated: this does exactly the same:

```
char get_symbol(int m) {
  return 'A' + m % 3;
}
```

It also does the modulo operation inside the function because (at least in your original function) calling `get_symbol` with values out side the interval [0..2] will lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: What made you assume he wants an array of chars?

Comment: @Yunnosch done, but not really necessary because when the program ends the output buffer is flushed anyway.

Comment: @Roi His verbatim description _"I want to print random chars and save them all in one array"_ made me assume this. But as I was still not 100% sure, I wrote: _"You **probably** want...."_

Comment: That is why you should not rush to answer a question until the problem is clear. `sym` is unknown as you mentioned as well and you removed it, when it might be necessary for his assignment. OP needs to be more clear.

Comment: @Roi changed the answer. Anyway, this code simply does what he wrote in the description.

Comment: @Jabberwocky No, it also does quite some explanation of what they need to get an answer to their "Why?" question. Otherwise I'd not consider this a helpful answer to the question as asked. ;-)